Unable to open cmd and have it execute a psexec function with button and computer name text box in visual studio
As the title says im making an app to help with Help Desk tasks. One of which being PSexec'ing into a remote machine. Im using visual studio and have the button linked up as well as a text box for computer name input. Right now it will open CMD but under the Debug folder in visual studio and will not execute the Argument in my Process. lost on what is wrong.
 private void btnPsExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //WHY NO WORK????
 {
     string pcName = txtPcName.Text;
     string command = $"\\{pcName} psexec /s cmd";

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pcName))
     {
         try
         {                 

             // Create a new process to run the command
             ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
             {
                 FileName = "cmd.exe",
                 Arguments = command,
                 UseShellExecute = true,
                 CreateNoWindow = false,         
             };

             // Start the process (this will open a CMD session on the remote PC)
             using (Process process = new Process())
             {
                 process.StartInfo = processInfo;
                 process.Start();
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             HighlightableMessageBox msgBox = new HighlightableMessageBox("Error", $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
             msgBox.ShowDialog();
         }
     }
     else
     {
         HighlightableMessageBox msgBox = new HighlightableMessageBox("Input Error", "Please enter a PC name.");
         msgBox.ShowDialog();
     }
 }type here

Expected this to work as ive also made a button to just open file explorer and navigate to one of my servers. works just fine with much the same code. however this one just will not execute the text listed in the string "command".

Are you saying code works when running the executable but not inside Visual Studio?  Visual Studio does not automatically run As Admin unless you start VS by right click on VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Should it be: string command = $@"/k psexec \\{pcName} cmd";?

string command = $@"/k psexec \{pcName} cmd"; worked, THANK YOU
